# Multiple Objects in a Symfony Form

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to build a form that requests your current employment and your previous employment and the object looks like this

```
class Employment {

    private $id;
    private $employerName;
    private $jobTitle;

    //this is a relationship to the class below
    private $address;
    private $phone;
}

class Address {

   private $city;
   private $state;
   private $zip;
}
```

The address is inside the Employment object.

I can build a form like this

```
$builder = $this->createFormBuilder($employment);
$builder
    ->add('employerName', 'text')
    ->add(
        $builder->create('address', 'form', array('by_reference' => ?))
            ->add('city', 'text')
            ->add('state', 'text')
    )
```

But this only gets the current employer.

## Question

How do I set it up to put 2 of the same object into 1 form?  I do not want to create another form, I need it to be in the same form.  I have thought about creating a parent however then I need to attach the Doctrine in order for it to work.

Any thoughts?

Comment: A form collection cannot help you to achieve that ?

Comment: @ceadreak no, a collection is when you have multiple items that are within a parent, something that is dynamic.  If you see an obvious way to utilize collections for this situation please let me know.  Maybe I didn't explain it well enough.

Comment: Explain what you mean by one form?  One HTML form?  Or one Symfony 2 form?  If the later then why?

Comment: I am not sure this is the right way or not. But you can create two field with address1 and address2 in your Employment with relation to address entity.

Comment: @Cerad it is the latter, the reason is for simplicity of the form  I have never believed in doing something out of ease for my self.  It's always about user experience.  I think the only way to do this is have a parent to employment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved by putting the data into a new FormType like this

```
class EmploymentFormType extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

        $builder
            ->add('current', new CurrentEmploymentFormType(),array(
                'data_class' => 'RLD\AppBundle\Entity\Employment'))
            ->add('previous', new PreviousEmploymentFormType(),array(
                'data_class' => 'RLD\AppBundle\Entity\Employment'))
        ;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'employment';
    }

}
```

This situation is different than most with an [embedded form type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html) its more dynamic and you are really repeating the form.  Where this situation is calling the same object but the lables are different so two types are acceptable.  Cerad was close with his answer but for some reason i was getting errors when trying to put it together as he suggested.  I found  solution to my issue when coming across an answer [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/symfony2/DjwwzOfUIuQ).  It was still slightly off but with a little tweaking with the guidance of Symfony errors I was able to get it working.  With this format I was able to build in the controller like this...

```
$form = $this->createForm(new EmploymentFormType());

return $this->render('RLDAppBundle:Default:test.html.twig', array(
     'form' => $form->createView(),
));
```

Hope this helps someone else because I didn't realize a form type could be entered as a type.  The more you know!

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comment about a single form, I think you may be over thinking the problem a bit.  You just need to use an array to pass two employment objects to a single form.

```
$data = array(
    'current'  => new Employment(),
    'previous' => new Employment(),
);
$builder = $this->createFormBuilder($data);
$builder
    ->add('current',  new EmploymentFormType())
    ->add('previous', new EmploymentFormType())
;
```

The answer assumes that you have defined an EmploymentFormType suitable for reuse.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html

Comment: The error I get when trying this is `The form's view data is expected to be of type scalar, array or an instance of \ArrayAccess, but is an instance of class RLD\AppBundle\Entity\Employment. You can avoid this error by setting the "data_class" option to "RLD\AppBundle\Entity\Employment" or by adding a view transformer that transforms an instance of class RLD\AppBundle\Entity\Employment to scalar, array or an instance of \ArrayAccess.`  Ideas?

Comment: Consider doing what the error message suggests in your EmploymentFormType.

Comment: I have but I get the error `Attempted to call method "createView" on class Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder`
I am trouble shooting now.

Comment: this is called in the controller correct?  Is there any special way to render this?  I am using `return $this->render('AppBundle:Default:test.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));`

Is that right?  I am getting the odd error above. `Attempted to call method "createView" on class Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder`

Comment: got it, I will post the answer shortly.

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: How do you make a form type suitable for reuse.  I still haven't found that.